# How to change the robot_base_frame frame based on forward/reverse driving in NAV2

Tags: ros2, nav2

What is the best way to change the robot_base_frame based on the direction you are driving? For a normal car, it has symmetrical behavior when driving forward/backwards so it does not matter much. But for articulated vehicles, where you have a pivot point in the middle of the vehicle, it will have a different angle in the rear relative to the front part of the vehicle. This has significant impact on the performance when driving in reverse, if the robot_base_frame is not set to the rear link of the vehicle. However, for forward driving, it is preferred to set it to the front link.

This means that when a goal pose is sent, the planner needs to set the start and goal pose relative to the robot_base_frame depending on whether it is the reverse or forward direction. Any ideas?

Here is a picture of the kinematics of an articulated vehicle [[Source]](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Articulated-vehicle-modeling-configuration-under-the-influence-of-slip-angles_fig4_259669662):
[image]